# Cycle through text with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to cycle through text applying a class to random words using only JS?

I want to create something similar to this (http://codepen.io/BrianDGLS/pen/wBgXwo) but with out having to define multiple span tags with ids.

```
var ids = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h",
                 "i", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s",
                 "t", "u"];

function shuffle(array) {

var item = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];
var remove = array[Math.floor(Math.random() * array.length)];

document.getElementById(item).className = "shine";
document.getElementById(remove).className = "";

setTimeout(function () {
    shuffle(ids);
}, 1000);
}
window.onload = shuffle(ids);
```

Comment: You could just use `document.getElementsByTagName("span")[random]` and refer to numbers rather than letters/ids.

Answer (score 1):

Because of how HTML works you can't put a class on a textnode. You can only put a class on an element which may or may not contain textnodes.

What you can do though is cut up the text in JavaScript so you don't manually need to add the spans.

Here is a live example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YPNvZy the animation behaviour is a little bit strange. I'm not sure what causes that, but it does demonstrate how to automatically split the text.

I've also opted to keep the structure like a poem, I'm not sure if you want that.

```
var poem = "I will arise and go now,\n"
 + "and go to Innisfree,\n"
 + "And a small cabin build there,\n"
 + "of clay and wattles made;\n"
 + "Nine bean-rows will I have there,\n"
 + "a hive for the honey-bee,\n"
 + "And live alone in the bee-loud glade.\n"
 + "And I shall have some peace there,\n"
 + "for peace comes dropping slow,\n"
 + "Dropping from the veils of the morning\n"
 + "to where the cricket sings;\n"
 + "There midnight’s all a glimmer,\n"
 + "and noon a purple glow,\n"
 + "And evening full of the linnet’s wings.\n"
 + "I will arise and go now,\n"
 + "for always night and day\n"
 + "I hear lake water lapping\n"
 + "with low sounds by the shore;\n"
 + "While I stand on the roadway,\n"
 + "or on the pavements grey,\n"
 + "I hear it in the deep heart’s core.";

var lines, i, div, divs = [];
lines = poem.split("\n");
for (i = 0; i < lines.length; i += 1) {
    div = document.createElement("div");
    div.className = "line";
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(lines[i]));
    divs.push(div);
    document.getElementById("container").appendChild(div);
}

function shuffle(divs) {

    var item = divs[Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length)];
    var remove = divs[Math.floor(Math.random() * divs.length)];

    item.className = "shine";
    remove.className = "";
}
setInterval(function () {
    shuffle(divs);
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to add a style, the words must be in individual elements.

However you don't necessarily need to look them up by an id using an array since they are already effectively in an array in the DOM which you can access using node.childNodes[].